# Use Terminal menus without using mouse?

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I've recently installed Linux Mint 18.1 and I'm using Terminal all the time.  My Terminal is GNOME version 3.18.3.

There are various menus in the GNOME Terminal. In Windows you typically access something like "Edit" by going Alt-E. This doesn't work for Terminal.  Is there any way of of accessing these menus without being forced to use the mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GNOME Terminal, you can access the menu using <kbd>F10</kbd>. Press that to open the File menu, then use the arrow keys to navigate inside that menu (<kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>) or to open other menus (<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd>).

You can enable menu shortcuts (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> for the File menu etc.) by checking the “Enable mnemonics” option in the preferences:

[image: Screenshot of the Preferences dialog]

You can also disable the <kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut here.

Comment: Thanks... had found the mnemonics checkbox in the mean time...!  But not the F10 way.